# Re-Establishing connection to Proxy Server

Tags: java, curl, post, proxy, httpurlconnection

I have an interesting scenario here. I have a proxy server address that is supposed to provide me a new exit IP every time I make an HTTP request to it. I have noticed that the exit IP will change only after I restart the program, as opposed to every loop iteration. Below is my source.

Loop calls getHTML every iteration:

```
    String result = getHTML("https://wtfismyip.com/text");


public static String getHTML(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
    InetSocketAddress addy = new InetSocketAddress("example.proxy.com", 1234);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addy);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    conn.disconnect();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Result will continue to be the same IP every time, until I restart the program. I feel like some stream or socket hasn't been closed yet and it keeps the connection alive.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem. The TCP socket was being kept alive, and would allow it to keep tunneling to the proxy without reconnecting.

I needed to add this statement somewhere in my code, I put it at the beginning of this class's initialization.

```
    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
```